# Sending a mail from SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

is it possible to send an email with SQL Server? I would like to be able to create a procedure for sending an email. It seems that I have to do some configuration according to this [site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/ms175951.aspx) but I don't have admin access on my machine. How can I achieve that ?

Thanks for your help !!

P.S : I am working on Windows

Comment: I don't think there is anyone here that can grant you admin privileges to the SQL Server. :-)

Comment: @Simen I bet Chuck Norris can

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have limited privileges on the SQL Server why don't you write the query to obtain the users' names, email adresses and forgotten DVD titles and send the email from you application?

As long as you have access to an SMTP server you should be good to go.

Or you could always try the obvious:

```
 USE YourDB;
 GRANT CONTROL SERVER TO ME AS (JON_SKEET OR CHUCK_NORRIS);
 GO
```

:-)

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I think this is the best to achieve that.

Answer (score 1):

[xp_sendmail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189505.aspx) is the command you want for older versions of SQL Server. Note that this is being removed from future versions, so for versions which support it use [Database Mail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175887.aspx).

**EDIT** Sorry - just read your full post. If you don't have the rights to enable mail sending, you'll need to speak to the admin who has. Server security is not designed to be "worked-around". Why does the mail have to be sent from SQL Server?

Comment: I am developping a videoClub project and we want to be able to send an email to users who do not send back the DVDs, or CDs, etc that they borrow. I am writing a procedure that will be called in a thread.

Comment: Well, if it has to be done in SQL Server, then you'll need to get someone with admin rights to reconfigure the server appropriately. Could you write an application to do this, perhaps run as a scheduled task?

Comment: Yeah that's what we are going to do. Thx for your advice

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [CLR Stored Procedure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131094.aspx).
See this example for instance: [Send Email from SQL Server Express Using a CLR Stored Procedure](http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1795)

Sending it via .NET would allow you to relay on a external SMTP and not having to configure Database Mail.

Comment: But if he doesn't have the privileges, he is probably unable to deploy a CLR assembly for email on the server.